# Foursquare Android Hash Key generation

Tags: android, foursquare

The new app creation page in foursquare asks me for Android HasKeys. It looks very similar to the SHA1 key. is it the same. Else How do I get a android Hash key?Attached pic from the website. The command also given below. How do I get mystore.keystore? Should I register in google developer site to get one? Please help

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt from your jre/bin folder by holding shift and right clicking it will say open comand prompt here. Then input your file path to your key store. If that doesn't work try this http://limbaniandroid.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-get-hash-key-for-integarte.html?m=1#comment-form

But that looks like it want your md5 thumbprint that you can see as you sighn your app in the last screen in eclipse.

look at this

[How do I generate my MD5 and SHA1 thumbprints using eclipse for debug keystore (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657142/how-do-i-generate-my-md5-and-sha1-thumbprints-using-eclipse-for-debug-keystore/18657143#18657143)

Comment: Can u tell me which keystore I must point to?Is it a java certificate?

Comment: Thre is not comment in the link u gave. think It was deleted. Can I follow the steps in tht URL?

Comment: Yah the instructioned code from the link will give you your hash key. The keystore if you want to run it in debug mode can normally be found under c:/users/YOURPCNAME/.android/debug keystore if you want a signed one you were prompted were to save it upon signing your application. If you have not published your app you can sighn it under a new keystore and just watch were you save it.